# Why do large companies prefer Spring over Java EE?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

While looking for the job, i have attended some job interviews at companies, that work at financial sphere. Every company uses Spring Framework as main framework for development. And almost everywhere I was told 'We need proved and stable technologies, that is why we use Spring.'

I would like to know, as I can't understand, why Spring is more popular and 'safer', than Java EE (for example, Spring MVC is used more, than JSF, while both provide almost the same functionality)?

How it is possible, that native Java EE functionalities are less stable, than third-libraries?

Comment: JSF and Spring MVC are very different technologies. JSF is a component-based framework that is centered around server-side rendering of views. Spring MVC is focused more on the routing and handling of HTTP requests and does not impose a particular view/templating framework on the developer.

Comment: Note: Spring != Spring MVC, JSF != JavaEE. Spring MVC is an optional component of the Spring framework, JSF is an optional component of the JEE specification. You are very free to use JEE components, but use Apache Wicket for the front-end. The same with Spring.

Comment: Gimby, I just take this two technologies as example, I know, that both of them are only parts of framework/specification. =)

Comment: In any case the answer is "they're not". But what is true is that plenty of people struggle to understand how to apply these technologies, and more so with JEE than with Spring in my experience.

Comment: This question is very fair and according with Stackoverflow standards. It is not primarily opinion-based because, the question is not about Spring better that JEE, but which are the forces that push financial companies to support Spring rather than JEE.

Comment: @rdllopes yeah its a super valuable question . Its right on the edge of unanswerable tho. I wish such questions had a place on SE

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some reasons:

1. Spring was already there: J2EE was ugly (no Dependency Injection, no conversion over configuration and lot of scares from EJB2, ouch). Java EE "stole" all good ideas from Spring, and it is in fact lighter and easier than previous versions. But now, everybody already uses Spring. It means a lot of production code, lot of well tested products and so on. In the end, why do people in UK/USA use English units? (There is a huge cost to change)
2. Spring is lighter: You do not need a heavy Java EE application server, you can deploy your application in a web container such as Tomcat.
3. Spring offers a ton of features which are not available as Java EE standards, such as Spring Batch or Spring Integration. You can use Spring features with Java EE standards, but it should be supposed Spring works better with Spring, shouldn't it?
4. Spring Aspect-oriented programming is more flexible and power that Java EE interceptors. You can use third-party AOP with Java EE but you can have this out-of-the-box from Spring.
5. Spring moves faster. Spring can release often and faster because it is no standard and only one vendor. So, it is not required JCP ballots, approvals, etc. The reaction to market requirements is much faster. Some current examples: cloud, mobile, social computing.

Ironically, I have "got" a lot ideas from:
http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2011/11/21/why-i-will-use-java-ee-jee-and-not-j2ee-instead-of-spring-in-new-enterprise-java-projects-in-2012/

Comment: You can and should deploy Java EE in Tomcat. And what I mean is Java EE Web Profile, which is lightweight. This is a common misconception but a serious one.

Comment: @MaciejSitko, absolutely true. Since JAVA EE 6, Java EE provides that  lightweight profile that is deployable in Tomcat. Good note.

Comment: I disagree with you, pleas see this : https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/why-i-will-use-java-ee-instead-of.html

Answer (score 9):

> While looking for the job, I have attended some job interviews at
>   companies, that work at financial sphere. Every company uses Spring
>   Framework as main framework for development. And almost everywhere I
>   was told 'We need proved and stable technologies, that is why we use
>   Spring.'

I work in financial domain since several years - so I can speak from my experience.

Many financial service providers I know had a major upgrade to their enterprise software stack at around 2006-2008, at a time when the disillusion about EJBs were at its peak after several unmaintainable and poorly written EJB projects. So in-order to upgrade their system and also to attract developers, they began to re-implement their stuffs in Spring and Hibernate, also it was a logical step for them to start new projects in the *state of the art frameworks* (which at that time were Spring, Hibernate and Wicket)

But since then financial crisis broke out and not many financial service companies think of investing that much money in new development unless it is very critical. Most do not care whether Java EE 6 or 7 was launched and some of the old arguments do not hold good anymore or so.

So they would like to believe that what they have is **safer**, **faster** etc (which may or may not be true)

Answer (score 8):

One thing that makes Spring attractive to developers, especially at big organizations like financial companies, is that it lets them take more control over their middleware. With pure Java EE, developers are at the mercy of an operations group that has very different goals than they have. In many cases operations wants to avoid messing with anything that works, every upgrade is a chance for things to go wrong, and it's not like they're the ones who see the benefits from upgrades, so that makes their choices very conservative. That can mean developers get stuck with obsolete versions of an application server, and if a problem comes up the developers have to work with the vendor's technical support (so you have to convince the vendor you have a problem and reproduce it under the conditions they specify), then coordinate with operations to implement the fix (which of course means justifying your request to an organization with different priorities from you). Developers like to minimize this kind of thing whenever possible.

Having Spring in the application gives the developers more freedom to update more of their infrastructure on their own schedule.

Comment: @Alex: happy i could help. this is something you don't realize until you've seen how these organizations work.